# Bind WPF Expander.IsExpanded property to ListBox.ItemCount with IValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, ivalueconverter, expander

I have a ListBox that shows search results, grouped by their type, implemented like this:

```xml
<ListBox.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                <Expander.Header>
                                    <TextBlock Margin="10 5 0 0">
                                        <TextBlock.Text>
                                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}: {1}">
                                                <Binding Path="Name" />
                                                <Binding Path="ItemCount" />
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </TextBlock.Text>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </Expander.Header>
                                <Expander.Content>
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                </Expander.Content>
                            </Expander>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
</ListBox.GroupStyle>
```

This is working fine.

Now I want to collapse the Expander if there are 10 or more items in a group (only after count changes, keeping the possibility for the user to expand and collapse manually). How can I achieve this?

I wrote an `IsLessThanConverter : IValueConverter` that takes a parameter and returns true if the passed value is less than the parameter.

However, I don't know how to integrate this converter here. I tried something like this, but the converter is never called:

```xml
<Expander IsExpanded="{Binding Path=Count,
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                               Converter={StaticResource IsLessThanConverter},
                               ConverterParameter=10,
                               Mode=OneWay}">
    ...
```

Comment: The syntax is correct - as long as resource 'IsLessThanConverter' has been added to XAML too, some lines before. like `<conv:IsLessThanConverter x:Key="IsLessThanConverter" />` 
where 'conv' is the C# namespace of that converter

Comment: `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},` is probably an error an should be removed. In the multibinding you also use Count, but there its just the Count from the listbox grouping.

Comment: Thanks @lidqy for pointing me into the right direction! The resource was fine, I just left it out here for brevity. But you were right, `RelativeSource Self` was wrong, as Expander of course has no count. Additionally, the variable `Count` was wrong, it should be `ItemCount`.